# How do I verify if my e-mails are caught by Gmail's spam filter?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I'm concerned that e-mails I'm sending are caught by the Gmail spam filter. I'm sending emails via Amazon SES and I neither see reports nor bounces. However, I have zero responses on my emails which make it seem that emails may be in spam folders.

I checked http://www.blacklistmonitoring.com/ and my email address is not blacklisted.

How do I verify whether my e-mails are put in Gmail's spam folder?

Maybe the text looks spammy – how do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

Start by sending one to yourself and see where that ends up.

See this: http://knol.google.com/k/read-receipts-in-gmail#